# ExtJS 4.1: Buffered scrolling bug when zoom is enabled

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4.1, zooming

This seems to be a browser bug, which is very easy to reproduce.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/buffer-grid.html in latest Chrome, Firefox or IE.
2. Set zooming level to 110% (do Ctrl +)
3. Try to scroll the grid to the end of the range and reach the latest record with 5000 index (by dragging the scrollbar or via mouse wheel, no difference)

Issue: note, that it's impossible to reach the latest record. Scrollbar starts bouncing back by 20-30 records. This case is reproducible for buffered views only and even when javascript execution is stopped via debugger, but I can't repeat the same scenario with Ext 5.1: 
http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html

Has anyone faced this issue before? Any ideas how to fix this? Ext support answered that this is because of incorrect zoom handling in browsers and they don't really support such cases.

Comment: They must be lying. It works fine in [4.2.3](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/example/grid/buffer-grid.html). Upgrade, or dive in the code, find from which version it started working fine and find what changed.

Comment: In Ext 4.2.0 everything works fine, thanks. This is not an Ext bug, actually, and even not a javascript issue. I think this is a layout nuance.